# Installed liquid cooler, now pc shuts off immediately

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, overheating

My PC, which I built over two years ago (and has been running fine the entire time) is now shutting off about a second after I try to power it up after going from the stock AMD CPU cooler to a Corsair H80i. I used arctic silver 5 thermal compound. All the fans are spinning, and I can hear the pump when it starts up.

Through my preliminary googling, it looks like it could be either my CPU is overheating instantly, or my motherboard doesn't detect a CPU fan, but I don't know how to find out which one it is.

On my MSI motherboard, 1 light comes on before it shuts off.

Any help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

My PC's specs:
AMD FX6300,
4x2gb Kingston HyperX Black ram,
Nvidia GTX 770 2GB MSI Twin Frozr
Kingwin 750w PSU,
2x1tb hard drives

EDIT: never mind, it works

Comment: You could connect the old CPU fan. (Connect to the pins on the motherboard so it is detected. I am not suggesting to replace the new liquid setup. Just to make sure that lack of CPU fan detection does not trigger the shutdown).

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. I tried turning it on again and it worked without changing anything. And it seems to be turning on reliably, but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: That PSU has an interesting method of being 'off' :)

Anyway, I suggest posting the solution (trivial as it was) as an answer, waiting a but and then accepting your own answer.  Without that the post will get bumped to the front page every now and then until there is either an accepted answer of sufficiently upvoted answers.  Editing it as [solved] is a nice idea but not the way this site works.

Comment: @Hennes Oh, right. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I found out the real reason it was turning off immediately. The PSU switch was on the wrong setting (I.e. off), which for some reason was letting it turn on for a second. I recommend against Kingwin PSUs.

Answer (score 0):

CPU does not overheat instantly, so most likely to be the fan speed sensor.
BIOS might have an option to disable CPU fan checking; except you can't get to change it because PC shuts down... Connect the old fan just to fire it up and change the BIOS setting.